# Difference between [BsonId] and BsonClassMap.MapIdField

Tags: c#, mongodb

Using the [C# MongoDB Driver](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.10/), I'm trying to understand the main difference between the Attribute `[BsonId]` and the [`BsonClassMap.MapIdField`](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.10/apidocs/html/M_MongoDB_Bson_Serialization_BsonClassMap_MapIdField.htm) method used in `BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap`.

Less generally I'm trying to use a `string` field of a Model as my document's `Id` field. If I use the `[BsonId]` Attribute everything is working fine:

```
public class MyModel
{
    [BsonId]
    public string AStringId{ get; set; }
}
```

But if I try to **instead** register it as Id with `MapIdField` I then have a `System.FormatException: Cannot deserialize a 'String' from BsonType 'ObjectId'..` whenever I'm querying that Collection

```
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<MyModel>(cm =>
{
    cm.MapIdField(m => m.AStringId);
});
```

I'd like to know why this problem is happening and more generally what's the difference between those two ways to use a field as custom Id?

: *Don't RTFD me as the MongoDB C# driver documentation is awfully dry on that subject*

Thanks

Comment: The error you pasted indicates that you have some documents having `ObjectId` as `_id` and your .NET driver expects them to be strings since you're using `[BsonId]`. I don't see much difference between both approaches - you should be getting the same error if you're querying the same documents. Can you show your data then?

Comment: Hey @mickl, you are right, I'm migrating a collection's model in a method and I first used `[BsonId]` on both of my `AStringId` forgetting that my old version was using a classic ObjectId on the_id field! So that totally explains that exception, thanks!
More generally how certain are you that both approach are identical?

Comment: Just tried to test and it behaves the same way in your case (coverts into `_id`). Generally I think it's the same approach as in EntityFramework - you can use attributes or run some methods to define the way your entity classes are mapped to database tables / documents

Comment: Maybe with the advantage of not invading your models definition with specific mongo Attributes when you use `registerMapping`, that'd be one good point